# Django REST login from server

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using AngularJS as client fw, and django rest framework. I'm at the authentication part and was wondering if it is possible to POST us/pw and then login the user at the backend and then be able to access using the @login_required.

I'd like to avoid using $cookies in the client and then if I'm not logged in server responds with a 404 and then angular redirects the user to login page. When a user is logged in the user will have access too the server.

Is is even possible to be logged in at django on localhost:8000 and then access from localhost:82?

For trying I've logged in to admin-page(now the user is logged in) and then accessing some info from localhost:82 which is not working

```
angular.js:11442 GET http://localhost:8000/website/api/order/?format=json 404 (Not Found)


@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #print(request.data['password'])
        username = request.data['username'];
        password = request.data['password'];
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password);
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request,user);
                return Response(200)
        else:
            return Response(404)
    else:
        return Response(404)
```

The validation works, when I type the real username and password I get 200 as a response, If I login with a admin account from the client shall I not be able to access the admin page if I type localhost/admin? Currently I'm not logged in when I try to access admin-page.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so accept it, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [`SessionAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) you have to be on the same host. The server has no possibility to check whether you are the same user when you access the page from a different host.

If your angular.js app is running on a different host, you should authenticate via [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) or some more sophisticated method like JSON WTA.